# Proof of eqn.(8) on pg.367 in Royden & Fitzpatrick "Real Analysis" fourth edition.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

The equation is given below:

> [image]

And the definition of integrale for nonnegative functions is given below:

> [image]

And we already proved the following:

> [image]

**My Proof is: **

It follows directly from the definition of the integral and from $(5)$ in proposition $(8).$

**My question is:**

Is this proof correct or there are some precise details that should be included ?

Comment: It does follows from (5).  All you need is the fact that any simple function $\leq g$ a.e. is also $\leq h$ a.e..

Comment: So my proof is correct and no other details required? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: No more details required.

Comment: See pages 81~82. Basically the same thing. Only few lines, so it is okay to omit them.

Comment: @xbh but we are now in a general measure space and the definition of the integral for nonnegative functions is different.

Comment: @Secretly That's why I said "basically". See those pages, and you simply need to replace all "bounded functions of finite support" by "simple functions" and you are good to go.